# Rudin's definition of $L^1(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Ch.1, he defines $L^1(\mu)$ as the collection of all **complex-measurable** functions $f$ on $X$ such that

$$\int_{X} |f| d\mu < \infty$$

Later in the chapter and in the exercises, he considers functions $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ that are in $L^1(\mu)$.

Sorry for the hair splitting, but why does Rudin's definition allow non-negative functions (possibly extended real-valued) to be in $L^1$?

Comment: Isn't it just because you can look at $f$ as a function $X \to \mathbb C$?

Comment: @YvesStalder I think the issue is that $[0,\infty]$ is not a subset of $\mathbb C$. If $f$ takes on the value $\infty$ then we can't say that $f: X \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: @littleO Of course! I didn't read thé brackets correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If $f: X\to [0,\infty]$ is $\mu$-integrable, then $f$ is finite almost surely. So there is a measurable function $g: X\to [0,\infty[$ that agrees with $f$ almost everywhere and for most purposes you can just replace $f$ by $g$.

If Rudin says that $f: X\to [0,\infty]$ is in $L^1(\mu)$, it just means that $f$ has a finite integral.